# Include Vimeo in website without allow advertising cookies

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, vimeo, oembed

We are developing a website which gave the user the possibility to disable advertising cookies, is it possible to Vimeo Player to deny any cookie to be setted?

We would like a functionality like youtube-nocookie that allow to include YT iFrame wthout letting it set advertising cookies.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I guess at this time you already figured this out, but you can use the parameter `dnt` "do not track" in your Vimeo url: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/oembed/videos

Just set `dnt=1` in your Vimeo URL.

Comment: I added the dnt=1 and it did seem to get rid of one or two of the Vimeo cookies but I the "__cf_bm" cookie is still being created/used. I asked Vimeo Support about this and they said it's from Cloudflare and can not be disabled. More details: https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/get-started/reference/cloudflare-cookies/#__cf_bm-cookie-for-cloudflare-bot-products